# Get data from JS array of objects

Tags: javascript, object

Probably very easy question, but I couldn't find solution.
How to get data from this object?
[image: Object in console.log]

That how it looks in consolo.log()

UPDATE:

Thank you for you answers.
That what I used before and it worked, but when I try on this array it returns error.

```
console.log(array[1].data);
```

[Output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slES7.png)

UPDATE2:

So I tried to make it a text, but I couldn't.

```
    console.log(tempArray);
    console.log("String: " + tempArray.toString());
    console.log("Stringify: " + JSON.stringify(tempArray));
```

Here is output: 
[Stringify attempt result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjAGZ.png)

Maybe there is something wrong with how I create this array.

```
let tempArray = [];
```

And in the loop

```
tempArray.push({"id": id, "data": data.routes[0].geometry});
```

Thank you, 
Dmitry

Comment: this is an array use something like `array[0].date` or loop to get all date values

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry but I was suppose to clarify it in question. I tried it before and it didn't worked, that is why I asking this question. I edited question.

Answer (score 0):

That's an array of objects, so you would get elements from it like so:

```
console.log(obj[i].data)
```

Where **i** is the element (numbered 0 through 2) that you want to access.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry but I was suppose to clarify it in question. I tried it before and it didn't worked, that is why I asking this question. I edited question.

Comment: Please post the output of console.log(data) in text format so I can see exactly what the object looks like.

Comment: Thank you again for your time. I updated my question to explain what I'm doing there.